# Oracle database to GitLab

Tags: git, oracle, gitlab, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to make a connection between a live database and GitLab through Oracle SQL Developer. I have a connection to GitLab working in "Team", and an active connection to an oracle database. How can I connect the two? I think it has something to do with the "Migration Repository" option, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 'connection' - you'll create your GIT project.

You'll then generate your source code from your database contents to files, which I'm assuming then would be controlled via GIT.

There's no concept of doing a COMMIT on a table in SQL Developer. Rather, you do the work, get the code, save it to your file, then commit that.

Apologies if I've completely misunderstood your question.

Comment: I'm trying to setup a Version Control Management for packages of a Database. Besides having them in the repository and manually putting them in the "live" database is there a way to automaticly do it?

Comment: There's a way to automatically gen the files if you ALREADY have a db you want to control. Auto deploying them from Git to a database though? There are 3rd party solutions out there, some are free, some are $$$.

Comment: Thank you. Any 3rd party program you'd recommend?

Comment: I can't really rec/endorse something in my position, but I've been impressed by this solution http://www.dbmaestro.com/oracle-sql-developer-ide/

Answer (score 0):

Third party solutions are not necessary. There is indeed a way to automatically do that within GitLab.

What you need to do, is to setup a yaml file that automatically updates your Oracle database whenever a new change is pushed to the repository. This change will then be instantly stored in the database and can be seen in SQL Developer.

The yaml command to update your database with a trigger when pushed should look something like this:

"for /F %%i in ('git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r %CI_COMMIT_SHA%') do sqlplus YourDatabaseConnectionHere"

Answer (score -1):

For what it is worth, we built a commercial tool that bridges Oracle to Git. It helps you manage your Oracle database objects with Git and you can push/pull your code to/from GitLab: https://www.gitora.com